# Granting privileges to ALL objects in a database - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, backup, database-backups

I'm trying to backup my database with:

```
pg_dump my_database > backup.sql
```

unfortunately there are no privileges set for many objects in the database,

therefore the command does not work!

---

Furthermore this does not grant privileges as expected:

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE my_database TO root
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: A bit old thread on pgsql-admin but I believe it's still relevant - http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2004-02/msg00025.php.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to dump entire database much simpler solution is working as a superuser (postres by default). Isn't it an option?

pg_dump -U postgres my_database > backup.sql